# Put css class directly on element or its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I need to color one of its children div. I was thinking of setting a CSS class to the parent div instead of directly on the children div since I have a javascript class that already have a reference to the parent, so I don't need to lookup for the children.

Is it a bad pratice ? Could it cause me trouble in the future ?

Here an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJgzJp?editors=110

html:

Is this better

```
<div class="parent1 whatIPrefer">
  <div class="children1">
  </div>
</div>
```

than

```
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="children2 meh">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

.parent1{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
    }

```
.children1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.whatIPrefer .children1{
  background-color: gold;
}

.parent2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.children2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.meh{
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

More Context: I want to display problematic items in a red in my page. There could be many items colored that way, my javascript code to colour it look like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < this._report.WorksheetSectionIDs.length; i++) {
    var worksheetSection = this._report.GetWorksheetSection(i);

    if (worksheetSection._worksheet._grid.getColumns().length != columnsCount) {
        this.Errors.push("Worksheet " + worksheetSection._sectionID + " doesn't have the right number of columns.");
        worksheetSection.SetInErrorState();
    }
}
```

where each worksheetSection has a reference to the parent element, so I can easily add a class to it.

Comment: The first approach seems to be better...however to be safe give classes to all your elements

Comment: is height and width fix for every div you should create new class and apply in all div element

Comment: What happens is you have multiple child div's?

Comment: Better to avoid using IDs for styling, you may end up with specificity wars! Other than that it doesn't really matter, as long as it's most readable to yourself.

Comment: I agree with Ben, it's dependent on your use. I think of classes like defining objects (parent class="vehicle", child class="truck") where you define all common properties on the parent and specifics on the children. If it's all common properties then just use the parent class and save the child classes for finer targeting when needed

Comment: @SilencePeace I agree but it is just for this simplified example

Comment: @MarcAudet Could have multiple div, but my css selector will target one that is the only one with the css class

Comment: @sdcr You're right, I changed my example

Comment: @wunth That's a good point, in my case I want to display that a parent have an error, and to show that, only the children div get a color. It might make more sense to put the class on the parent

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is largely dependent on your use case. You did not provide much context, so this may be the best or not the best application for targeting your child `div`.

You can access the child of a `div` using the child selector for css:

`.whatIPrefer > div { styles }`

[Here is an excellent article on selecting children of a parent element](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) - check it out.

Hope this helps. Please comment below with any other questions. Thanks

Comment: This answer your question?

Comment: I haven't thought about the child selector, which could be a 3rd option (actually probably better than the descendant selector). As for context, I want to indicate that a parent has an error, and for that I color that children (since its the only elements colorable, which my example ommited). It seems that it would make more sense to put the class on my parent to put emphasis on it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on web structure, and on elements, that you are styling. For example, if you know, that header will be just one, you can easilly style directly the header, but if there is more headers with different styles, for example header in body, header in head and so on. In that case it is good to style throw parent element.

In my projects, i always style throw parent elements, sometimes it is useless, but it is a good practise and you never know, when your web will need new elements.